# How to compute two points, each on a line, equally distant from a given point?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have a set of five points: a, b, c, d, e. I want to compute the corners Q, R of the triangle below. The tricky part is that the distances between Q-e and R-e must be equal.

[image]

I'm using the formula for a straight line *L(x)=kx+m* like [this cute webpage](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-2points.html) shows. The first intersecting point P is calculated as follows.

```
double k_ab = (b.Y - a.Y) / (b.X - a.X);
double m_ab = a.Y - k_ab * a.X;
double k_cd = (d.Y - c.Y) / (d.X - c.X);
double m_cd = c.Y - k_cd * c.X;

double p = (m_cd - m_ab) / (k_ab - k_cd);
Point P = new Point(p, k_ab * p + m_ab);
```

Then, I get stuck. Since I don't know the exact x coordinate for the point Q, I have to use it as a variable. Even on paper I get brain poofage because there's too much moving parts and subcomputation. I'm sensing that I've chosen a poor and inefficient approach to the problem, so if anybody has a suggestion how to reformulate the problem to make the solution more apparent, I'd be delighted.

Comment: Do you need a 100% precision of Q and R?

Comment: @SantiGil Nope. Although I'll be doing it a lot so trial/error and iterative approaching might be too demanding. But no, nobody will die of a little epsilon missing.

Comment: @jameslarge I see where you come from but it actually is C#, JavaScript and Java. I've asked about the mathematical part at math.stack and got the answer. This one is strictly about implementing the algorithm in **any** of those languages.

Comment: @FirstStep I already have [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912969/finding-third-side-of-a-minimal-triangle). And I've got the formulas but on paper. It's specifically in one of the listed languages that I need to implement it and get stuck there. Good eyes, mate!

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger I don't know PQ nor PR. I have the small caps given (a through e), while the capitals (P through R) are to be computed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to find the x values of Q and R:

Let `f(x)` be the equation of the line that contains `a` and `b`.

Let `g(x)` be the equation of the line that contains `c` and `d`.

Then `f(Q_x) - e_y == e_y - g(R_x)`, and `Q_x - e_x == e_x - R_x`

Let `z = Q_x - e_x`

To calculate z, solve `f(e_x + z) - e_y = e_y - g(e_x - z)`, which is

```
k_ab * (e.x + z - a.x) + a.y - e.y = e.y - c.y - k_cd * (e.x - z - c.x)

k_ab * (e.x + z - a.x) + k_cd * (e.x - z - c.x) = 2 * e.y - a.y - c.y

k_ab * (e.x - a.x) + k_cd * (e.x - c.x) + k_ab * z - k_cd * z = "

z * (k_ab - k_cd) = 2 * e.y - k_ab * (e.x - a.x) - k_cd * (e.x - c.x) - a.y - c.y
```

So finally

```
z = (2 * e.y - k_ab * (e.x - a.x) - k_cd * (e.x - c.x) - a.y - c.y) / (k_ab - k_cd)
```

And `Q_x = e_x + z` and `R_x = e_x - z`. I'm sure you can figure the rest out from here.

[Try it here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/u4s6i28oaz)

[image: Example]

Comment: Let me get back to you in a while. I was doing something like that but applied the full formula *(e_x-Q_x)^2+(e_y-Q_y)^2* and put it equal to *(e_x-R_x)^2+(e_y-R_y)^2* resulting in a bunch of stuff that killed my will to live. You have no squares at all. How come?

Comment: @KonradViltersten the midpoint of Q and R is just (Q_x + R_x)/2 , (Q_y + R_y) / 2. Work backwards from there, and you'll see that no squares are necessary.

Comment: Seems to be correct. One thing I'm wondering about, though. You land in *a.y+c.y*. Where is that coming from? The reason for me asking is that when I compute the line equation, I get *Q(x)=k_ab x+m_ab* and I know that *Q(a.x)=a.y*, hence *m_ab=a.y-k_ab a.x*. But you seem to only have *a.y* there. What am I missing?

Comment: @KonradViltersten You're not missing a thing: I was. Edited

Comment: OMG - what a great page you linked to! ANd OMG - I finally start to get it (since I've found the miss in the result). Nevertheless, you helped me out, mate. Awesome!

Comment: @KonradViltersten Always glad to help. Also you might want to try the link again. I made a mistake in the graph a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

**I don't know if the following is true**, but if someone with trigonometry expierence confirms it, it may be helpful. I just want to help with my basic trigonometry knowledge.

You know `P` and `e`. Draw the line that contains this two points, and cross also the perpendicular to it. This perpendicular will cross the two initial lines in two points `A` and `B`. Let's play with the distances `(A,e)` and `(e,B)`.

If they are equal, `e` is in the `QPR` bisector. `Q = A` and `R = B`.

[image: Picture1]

And this is what I don't really know. If `(A,e)` is `x` times higher than `(e,B)`, the angle `PQR` will also be `x` times higher than the angle `PRQ`. In the example I have set `x` to 3. A triangle has 180º, and as you know `QPR` (it is part of the problem), `PQR` would be `(x / x+1) * (180º - QPR)` and `PRQ = (1 / x+1) * (180º - QPR)`.

[image: Picture2]

Knowing this angles, you know the gradient of the line that cross `Q`, `e` and `R`. Make it pass by `e`, and you will know `Q` and `R` where this line crosses the other two.